# Customizing QGIS print composer to use default layout created and custome table

Tags: qgis, qt

I am doing a cadastral application as a plugin and I want to export some table in data [in a model] with the parcels displayed [ the geometry ] to pdf file.

And I am thinking to do that using  a QGIS print composer.But while creating layout

- I was able to add loaded canvas
- I was able to add attribute table but here I want my custom data table to be rendered
- And I have added some lables and legened

Now what I really need is getting the loaded canvas with my data table in the layout prepared while clicking print composer.
what is the best way to get custome data to the print composer 
I am able to code in QGIS iface enviroment and am looking solution in that aspect.